how to configure fullfillment updates in amazon lex bot to send initial response and periodic updates about fullfillment
Scenario:
I have a Lambda function integrated with Amazon Lex (V2) for fulfillment, which calls an external API to process the user's raw input. The external API takes a considerable amount of time to process the data and return a response. During this delay, I want to notify the user that their request is being processed in the background. Once the processing is complete, I want to send the response back to Amazon Lex.
Requirements:

Notify the user that their request is being processed (in the background).
After processing is complete, send the result back to Amazon Lex.

Challenge:
How can I structure this workflow in Amazon Lex and Lambda so that:

The user is kept informed that their request is in progress.
Amazon Lex can later present the final response after the external API completes processing.

Here is my lambda code:
import json
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    raw_input = event.get('inputTranscript', '')

    print(f"Raw input from Lex: {raw_input}")
    
    json_payload = {
        "model": "llama3.1",
        "messages": [
            {"role": "user", "content": raw_input}
        ],
        "stream": False
    }
    
    llama_api_url = "https://b014-27-147-186-221.ngrok-free.app/api/chat"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    
    try:
        llama_response = requests.post(llama_api_url, json=json_payload, headers=headers)
        llama_response.raise_for_status()
        response_json = llama_response.json()
        message_content = response_json.get("message", {"No Content Available"})
    
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        message_content = f"Request failed: {e}"
    except ValueError:
        message_content = "Invalid JSON received from API."
    
    session_attributes = event.get('sessionState', {}).get('sessionAttributes', {})
    session_attributes['rawUtterance'] = raw_input
    intent_name = event.get('sessionState', {}).get('intent', {}).get('name', 'Unknown')
    
    response = {
        "sessionState": {
            "sessionAttributes": session_attributes,
            "dialogAction": {
                "type": "Close"
            },
            "intent": {
                "name": intent_name,
                "state": "Fulfilled"
            }
        },
        "messages": [
            {
                "contentType": "PlainText",
                "content": message_content
            }
        ]
    }
    
    print("Sending Response to Lex: {}".format(response))
    
    return response

I’ve enabled fulfillment updates with active status, providing an initial response and periodic progress updates, but it still waits for the Lambda function to finish before responding.
